# Linux Kernel Development on a Windows PC (Windows 7)

Tags: linux-kernel

Although I am quite acquainted with Solaris, I am new to the world of Linux kernel development. I have just started reading a famous book on Linux kernel development, which advices the reader to proceed only with a Linux system as well as the latest kernel source code available in hand.

I know there are lots of suggestions on the forum about how to selectively boot the PC with either Linux or Windows. Suggestions include the use of VMWare, Linux boot CD, USB, Linux installed on a Windows partition, etc.

But my question is, if I use VMWare or Linux boot CD, will I be able to do things like modifying the Linux kernel source code in order to add a new feature or fix a bug and then boot the system to see the changes in the kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use VMVare or any other virtual machine. Linux boot CD can't help you in this case.

To be able to boot system with a new kernel you should be able to change bootloader settings. In this case virtual machine environment don't differ from regular system installation. However to change bootload setting in Linux boot CD you have to rebuild boot CD iso and this is not the easiest task.